# Flash CS6 Android App Testing - No USB Device Found

Tags: android, air, flash-cs6

I'm trying to create a simple Android testing app with Flash CS6. I've put a circle onto a blank canvas and plugged in the Android device (a Google Nexus 4), enabled developer mode/ USB debugging, created a digital certificate and tried to publish the app, but whenever I do so it tells me no device is plugged in. I've heard something about a USB driver for Flash CS5, but heard nothing about CS6... How do I fix this?

Thanks, any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: If you can, grab an older version of the [AIR SDK from Adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html) (preferably 3.5 or 3.4). Find your current AIR SDK, and find `/lib/android/bin` in both. Backup your current bin folder and then replace it with the older version. I have never been able to get the Nexus 4 to work with the last few versions of the AIR SDK, but the older versions seem to work.

Comment: I already had AIR 3.4 installed. (The standard that came with CS6) I didn't install anything else. Do I need to install the Android SDK/some USB driver?

Comment: No, try updating to a newer AIR SDK. AIR 3.1-3.4 had some pretty big issues for mobile apps anyway. But yes, you do need the Android SDK installed for this to work. Once you do, you can use ADT commands `devices`, `start-server`, `kill-server` to try and get your device to show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you need a debugging USB driver for your app. The easiest way to get it is to install the PC management application from mobile manufacturer (Samsung, for example has [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/)), which usually includes debugging drivers.